# Where Google chrome old form post data

Tags: html

I did post on Chrome last month.

Sample :

```
<form action="unknown" method="post">
    <input id="name" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="detail" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="age" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="vb" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="button" value="post" />
</form>
```

How do I find???

Thank you..

Comment: Chrome does not store POST bodies.

Comment: Is it somewhere else?